# Alert box is unable to show a variable Order ID of the order placed

Tags: javascript, python, django

I am using a checkout page to allow users to place an order on my shopping website using Django. But once the checkout form is filled out and the submit button is clicked, an alert box pops up:

```js
$('#done').click(function(){
  console.log({{ord_id}})
  alert('Thanks for ordering with us. Your order Id is {{ord_id}} . Use it to track your order.');
  localStorage.clear();
})
```

Look at the variable inside the alert box string. I am unable to get its value:

[image: screenshot]

The function in views.py which points to the HTML page containing the JavaScript part looks like this:

```py
def checkout(request):
    if request.method=="POST":
        itemsJson=request.POST.get("itemsJson","")
        name=request.POST.get("name","")
        email=request.POST.get("email","")
        phone=request.POST.get("phone","")
        address=request.POST.get("address1","")+" "+request.POST.get("address2","")
        city=request.POST.get("city","")
        state=request.POST.get("state","")
        zip=request.POST.get("zip","")
        place_order=Order(itemsJson=itemsJson,name=name,email=email,phone=phone,
                address=address,city=city,state=state,zip=zip)
        place_order.save()
        orderid=place_order.check_id
        update=UpdateOrder(order_id=orderid,update_email=email,
                update_desc="Your Order has been Placed")
        update.save()
        params={'ord_id':orderid}
        return render(request,'shop/checkout.html',params)
    return render(request,'shop/checkout.html')
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

You must do it with [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals). So:

```
$('#done').click(function(){
  console.log({{ord_id}})
  alert(`Thanks for ordering with us. Your order Id is ${ord_id} . Use it to track your order.`);
  localStorage.clear();
})
```

Comment: Still not working @Danial using template literals its now not even showing the alert box

Comment: @PalashVishnani try ${{{ord_id}}}

Comment: nope ${{{ord_id}}} is also not working out for me

Comment: What does it show `console.log({{ord_id}})` ?

Comment: It shows nothing @Danial. I think views.py is unable to give me the dictionary object but everything inside the function definition is correct.

Comment: Maybe you doesn't pass `ord_id` parameter. Look : you do `return render(request,'shop/checkout.html',params)
    return render(request,'shop/checkout.html')` .  The `params` may doesn't pass.

Comment: Soo What should I do then? How can I pass params? @Danial

Comment: @PalashVishnani Based on your python code, params return just when method is `POST`, check this.

Comment: I am only using post method in my checkout page, `if request.method=="POST":` condition is working properly thats why all the data is getting stored in UpdateOrder and Order tables but only when it comes to this line: `return render(request,'shop/checkout.html',params)` then params is not returned to the HTML page. And also, once the return statement is called why is the compiler reading the line written after that, which contains one more return statement??????

Comment: @PalashVishnani try `return render(request,'shop/checkout.html',{'ord_id':orderid})` or something else to test returned params

Comment: Still not working maybe its a bug or something.

Comment: Try something else for `ord_id` value. Ex. `return render(request,'shop/checkout.html',{'ord_id':123})`

Comment: It is working for the return statement present outside the if condition. If I provide something like `{'ord_id':123}` in the return statement outside the if condition its working. But if I provide this same thing to the return statement present inside the if  condition, its not working

Comment: So maybe problem is in `place_order.save()
        orderid=place_order.check_id`

Comment: Watch these new changes in my code and the output for testing purpose also have a look at the terminal:  [link](https://imgur.com/a/4F6RiS9)

Comment: I saw. try this `return render(None, "shop/checkout.html", {"ord_id":orderid})`

Comment: @PalashVishnani have you problem yet?

Comment: Are you sure about view? I mean you do coding on right html view file.